# How to use JQuery getAttribute to use a custom attribute in a select option

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to populate the value of an input field with a custom attribute 'data-weight' and show it in the input value of #weight 'on change' of the select box #product_title_select. However I am unable to get this to work.

Below is the code I am trying to use.

I'm not familiar with using custom attributes and events, so any help would be most appreciated. Thank you.

```js
$(document).on('change', '#product_title_select', function () {
  document.getElementById('weight').value = event.target.getAttribute('data-weight');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="product_title_select">
    <option value="Select" data-weight="">Select</option>
    <option value="123" data-weight="ABC">Option 1</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="weight" value="">
```

Comment: `console.log(event.target)` inside your change handler callback would have shown you, that this is the `select` element itself. That element does not have any `data-weight` attribute. You could f.e. use `$(this).find('option:selected').data('weight')` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event.target` is referring the *SELECT* element (which does not have the attribute) and you are trying to access the attribute of the selected *OPTION* element.

You can try [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) like the following way:

```js
$(document).on('change', '#product_title_select', function () {
  document.getElementById('weight').value = $(this).find(':selected').data('weight');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="product_title_select">
    <option value="Select" data-weight="">Select</option>
    <option value="123" data-weight="ABC">Option 1</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="weight" value="">
```